# Get ios device real udid via phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to retrieve ios udid (The same as shown in itunes) via phonegap using device.uuid. I'm getting a different uuid each time I install the app, it seems that the uuid i got belongs to the application rather than the device.

Can someone confirm ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right. Please look at [this](http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/24/apple-udids/).

> Apple has started ramping up its efforts to deprecate the UDID – the
>   unique identifier that ties a user to a specific device, like an
>   iPhone or iPad. The company originally announced its intentions to
>   phase out the UDID’s use more than six months ago, with the release of
>   iOS 5, but it recently began to reject apps from the App Store which
>   are attempting to access those identifiers.

But can have a look at [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/SecureDeviceIdentifier) and [that](https://github.com/crashlytics/secureudid).